# Can I add content other than tasks to a timeline

Tags: list, custom-list, timeline

I have a list of marketing/advertisement campaigns that lists the current and planned ad campaigns, start dates, end dates, and other various info. Is it possible to roll the list items from this custom list into a timeline or is the timeline specific to task lists?

Answer (score 0):

2013 task lists have the new time line associated with that content type. Otherwise Ghantt chart views work with any other lists, given the correct info such as start / end dates. There is also the task list timeline web part that can showcase the items from the task list.

Comment: As I said, I am working from a custom list that is not a task list. The Gantt view is nice, but it is not what I am looking for. What I want to know is if there is a way to add a standard timeline web-part onto the page for a custom list and have it display list items with Start//End dates

Comment: There is a web part called under content rollup called "Project Summary" however it is bound to task lists as it relates to the content type called "tasks".  - sorry.